# How to create a utf-8 encoded file in java such that it shows as UTF-8 encoded when opened in notepad++/notepad or any other text editor

Tags: java, file, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have tried to create UTF-8 file using java using different readers.But after creating when I open the file it is not read as being UTF-8 encoded(I opened it in notepad++ and it was UTF-8 without BOM).

```
File fileDir = new File("c:\\temp\\test.txt");

Writer out1 = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(
    new FileOutputStream(fileDir), 
    Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder())
);

Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(
    new FileOutputStream(fileDir), 
    Charset.forName("UTF-8")
);
out.append("Website UTF-8").append("\r\n");
out.append("?? UTF-8").append("\r\n");
out.append("??????? UTF-8").append("\r\n");

out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: You say "when I opened the file it is not in UTF-8" and then you say it was "UTF-8 without BOM". You are contradicting yourself. In general you probably don't want to have a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) especially not in UTF-8 as Wikipedia explains, some XML parsers can't deal with it.

Comment: Normal UTF-8 is different from UTF-8 without BOM...You can see over there in the notepad++

Answer (score 1):

You are correctly writing a file in the UTF-8 encoding. (Note that you're not using `out1` and it's unnecessary).

Notepad++ tells you that the file is "UTF-8 without BOM". Why do you think this is not UTF-8?

BOM stands for [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). It's a special Unicode character to indicate if the bytes in a file are in little-endian or big-endian order. But for UTF-8 it has no meaning and its use is not recommended. From the Wikipedia article:

> The UTF-8 representation of the BOM is the byte sequence `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`. A text editor or web browser interpreting the text as ISO-8859-1 or CP1252 will display the characters ï»¿ for this.
>
> The Unicode Standard permits the BOM in UTF-8, but does not require nor recommend its use. Byte order has no meaning in UTF-8, so its only use in UTF-8 is to signal at the start that the text stream is encoded in UTF-8. The BOM may also appear when UTF-8 data is converted from other encodings that use a BOM.

Is there a special reason why you need a BOM to be included? If not, then don't worry about it. Some Java XML parsers cannot deal with an UTF-8 BOM properly and will give an error when you try to parse an XML document encoded in UTF-8 when it starts with a BOM.

Comment: I dont want BOM...I just need a clarification why after writing this code notepad /notepad++ is not showing the encoding as UTF-8(Normal).If you open with notepad++ you can see it is showing UTF-8 without BOM eventhough there is a UTF-8 option

Comment: If you have an UTF-8 file without a BOM, then ofcourse Notepad++ shows "UTF-8 without BOM"... why do you think that there is anything wrong? It is exactly what you need. Why do you think that "UTF-8 without BOM" means that the file is not UTF-8?